# margin right not working on canvas html5 and trouble with scroll bar removal

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have the following canvas:

[Codepen link](https://codepen.io/swagnikd/full/mwmGGo/)

**What I want**: Equal margin on both sides of canvas without any horizontal scroll bars.

**Problem**: `margin-right` property does not to work. I have seen some solutions that solve this problem by specifying a fixed width, but I cannot have a fixed width in my case. I want my canvas to adjust its width height according to the size of the window.

The following Javascript takes care of that:

```
window.addEventListener('resize' , resizeCanvas , false);

function resizeCanvas(){
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight/1.2;
}
```

So is there a different solution?

For the overflow problem, if I put `overflow-x: hidden` inside the `body` then only the scrollbar disappears but the problem persists. The canvas still extends past the screen hence the right border of the canvas is No longer visible.
[See here](https://codepen.io/swagnikd/full/NgjmWJ/)

Here is my code:

**HTML**

```
<body onload="start()">
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

**CSS**

```
body{

}

canvas{

    border: 1px solid black;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: #fff;

    margin: auto 50px auto 50px; /* works for left margin but not for right */

}
```

Thanks!

**Another thing:**

I have not set `width: 100%` for the canvas because it distorts the content inside it.

Comment: You're deliberately making the canvas as wide as the window. Adding margins on top will make the document wider than the window.

Comment: Are you saying that the following line is the problem? `margin: auto 50px auto 50px;` ?
If it is so, I also tried removing margin-top but nothing changed. https://codepen.io/swagnikd/full/VWbNgV/

Comment: I'm saying this: `canvas.width = window.innerWidth;` is the problem. If you don't want horizontal scrollbars but a margin on the sides, you obviously cannot make the canvas as wide as the window...

Comment: I understand. Thanks, Chris!

Answer (score 2):

As Chris is saying you need to set the `width` of the `canvas` lower than the full width of the page:

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 100;
```

Note that you need to take the `border-width` of the canvas and in your codepen the body also has a margin of `8px` into account as well:

```
canvas.width = window.innerWidth - 118;
```

Answer (score 2):

CSS `calc()` method is what you need. Just subtract the margins from 100% and you get the desired result. See the demo below. [CSS calc() reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/calc)

```js
function start() {

  var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 1.2;
  var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  function rand(min, max) {
    return parseInt(Math.random() * (max - min + 1), 10) + min;
  }

  function get_random_color() {
    var h = rand(1, 360);
    var s = rand(30, 100);
    var l = rand(30, 70);
    return 'hsl(' + h + ',' + s + '%,' + l + '%)';
  }

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  var balls = [];
  var ballCount = getRandomInt(2, 10);
  //document.getElementById('ballCountInfo').innerHTML = ballCount;
  //document.getElementById('box').innerHTML = ballCount;
  var startpointX = 100;
  var startpointY = 50;

  for (var i = 0; i < ballCount; i++) {

    var randValue = getRandomInt(20, 30);
    balls.push({
      x: startpointX,
      y: startpointY,
      vx: getRandomInt(3, 3) * direction(),
      vy: getRandomInt(1, 1) * direction(),
      radius: randValue,
      mass: randValue,
      color: get_random_color(),

      draw: function() {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(this.x, this.y, this.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2, true);
        ctx.closePath();
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fill();
      }
    });

    startpointX = startpointX + 50;
    startpointY = startpointY + 40;
  }


  function direction() {
    var chosenValue = Math.random() < 0.5 ? 1 : -1;
    return chosenValue;
  }

  function draw() {

    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    for (var i = 0; i < ballCount; i++) {

      balls[i].draw();
      balls[i].x += balls[i].vx;
      balls[i].y += balls[i].vy;

      if ((balls[i].y + balls[i].vy + balls[i].radius) > canvas.height || (balls[i].y + balls[i].vy - balls[i].radius) < 0) {
        balls[i].vy = -balls[i].vy;
      }
      if ((balls[i].x + balls[i].vx + balls[i].radius) > canvas.width || (balls[i].x + balls[i].vx - balls[i].radius) < 0) {
        balls[i].vx = -balls[i].vx;
      }
    }

    //  onBoxTouched();

    //collision check
    for (var i = 0; i < ballCount; i++) {
      for (var j = i + 1; j < ballCount; j++) {

        var distance = Math.sqrt(
          (balls[i].x - balls[j].x) * (balls[i].x - balls[j].x) +
          (balls[i].y - balls[j].y) * (balls[i].y - balls[j].y)
        );

        if (distance < (balls[i].radius + balls[j].radius)) {

          var ax = (balls[i].vx * (balls[i].mass - balls[j].mass) + (2 * balls[j].mass * balls[j].vx)) / (balls[i].mass + balls[j].mass);
          var ay = (balls[i].vy * (balls[i].mass - balls[j].mass) + (2 * balls[j].mass * balls[j].vy)) / (balls[i].mass + balls[j].mass);
          balls[j].vx = (balls[j].vx * (balls[j].mass - balls[i].mass) + (2 * balls[i].mass * balls[i].vx)) / (balls[i].mass + balls[j].mass);
          balls[j].vy = (balls[j].vy * (balls[j].mass - balls[i].mass) + (2 * balls[i].mass * balls[i].vy)) / (balls[i].mass + balls[j].mass);
          balls[i].vx = ax;
          balls[i].vy = ay;
        }
      }
    }

    raf = window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);
  }


  function onBoxTouched() {

    for (var i = 0; i < ballCount; i++) {

      if (balls[i].x + balls[i].radius > 600 && balls[i].x + balls[i].radius < 750 &&
        balls[i].y + balls[i].radius > 200 && balls[i].y + balls[i].radius < 350) {

        //var ele = document.getElementById("box");
        ele.style.backgroundColor = balls[i].color;

        balls.splice(i, 1);
        ballCount = ballCount - 1;

        if (ballCount == 0) {
          ele.style.fontSize = "x-large";
          ele.innerHTML = "Over";
        } else {
          ele.innerHTML = ballCount;
        }

        //document.getElementById('ballCountInfo').innerHTML=" "+ballCount;
      }
    }
  }

  window.requestAnimationFrame(draw);

  window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

  function resizeCanvas() {
    canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
    canvas.height = window.innerHeight / 1.2;
  }



}
```

```css
* {}

html,
body {}

canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: calc(100% - 40px);
  /*substract the total margin from 100% and will automoatically adjuts accordint to your need*/
  margin: auto 20px auto 20px;
  /* works for left margin but not for right */
}

#box {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: plum;
  border-radius: 5px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 600px;
  font-size: 72px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: white;
  line-height: 150px;
  text-align: center;
}

#info {
  float: left;
  font-size: 24px;
  color: #6D8390;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<body onload="start()">
  <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
</body>
```

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

instead of messing around with margins, just change the width of your canvas and center it.

CSS

```
canvas {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 90%!important;
}
```

HTML

```
<body onload="start()">
  <center>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  </center>
</body>
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/GEmLPL